# Convert external drive space, E, over to my internal, C, drive (or part of it)

Tags: conversion

Only Q/A on this is several yrs old...hoping things have changed. May as well try.

I want to download a torrent that is too big for my C drive. I bought a 1 T external before finding out about FAT32/NFTS.

Now I've researched, and I understand why I couldn't download the torrent. Have read several questions close to this, but want to know: Is it possible now, in 2023, to convert FAT32 to NFTS so I can download this huge torrent I want?

(Have tried 3rd party software. Their chat tells me it can't be done because they aren't on the same disc. After researching THAT, I finally got it, but am asking just in case they're wrong and there IS a way to convert an external 1 T drive -- or part of it -- to my internal C drive that is too small to download the torrent to.)

Thanks.

Comment: Geez,excuse typo in heading!

Comment: Are you saying your C drive is FAT32? Also, you can't "convert" one physical drive to another - physical drives remain separate entities

Comment: Or, did you want to "convert" your "external" drive to NTFS? If so, just format it, specifying NTFS as the filesystem

Comment: there's also the possibility to mount the external drive onto your C: drive, anywhere (almost) you want - https://www.windowscentral.com/how-mount-drive-windows-10

Comment: What you describe, what you want to do, is absolutely NOT possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 1 TB external drive, and you don't care to keep any of the existing data on that drive:

1. Format the external drive NTFS (or exFAT or ext4 if you have reason to do so, since those also accept files over 4 GB).
2. Change the location where the downloaded torrent is stored to the * 1 TB external drive*.

For example, using free [qBittorrent](https://www.qbittorrent.org/), open the *Options* dialog, select *Downloads*, and set the *Default Save Path* to a location on that external drive.

[image: Set download location in qBittorrent]

Now the downloads won't clutter up your C: drive, since they will go directly to the external dive, and there is the added advantage that the path to the folder might be shorter, helping to avoid files being rejected because path + filename is too long. You can use the file on an external drive just as conveniently as if it were on your C: drive.

**N.B.** Trying to reallocate space on an existing drive, particularly the *mounted* C: drive which holds the operating system, is an invitation to disaster. Also, take care that you format the *external 1 TB drive, **not** the C: drive*.